# Prove a function has only simple roots

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, rouches-theorem

I am working on old qualifying exams, and I have stumbled on a problem that looks somewhat like this:

> Prove that $f(z) = (z-1)^{50}e^z + .75(z+1)^{50}$ has exactly 50 simple zeroes with $\Re z > 0 $

(The actual problem is more general)

Now, proving the existence of 50 zeroes in the right plane is just a matter of Rouche's Theorem, that is clear to me. What I am unsure about is how to prove the simple part -- I have never seen a problem ask to prove this. Rouche's Theorem, as I understand, provides no information about the multiplicity of zeroes. The only theorems I know of that deal with multiplicity of zeroes is the Argument Principle or the Residue Theorem. Only the Argument Principle looks promising, but just toying with it, it seems impractical to implement.

Is there a standard method of proof or theorem that I am missing to prove something like this for a general function? Any *hints* on this particular problem would be appreciated!

Comment: Take the derivative. The derivative must share no roots with the function for all of the zeros to be simple.

Comment: Use the function $g(z)=(z+1)^{-50}f(z)=\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^{50}e^z+0.75$ for the argument principle. Note that $\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ maps the imaginary line to the unit circle, $e^z$ remains of absolute value $1$ and the $+0.75<1$ is not enough to prevent that from winding around $0$.

Comment: And don't think of Rouche's theorem as the go-to result to count zeros. That is an idea that students often get because they see it applied in theoretical results and from being asked over and over problems that have been specially designed to have an easy pair of functions that satisfy the hypothesis. While everything that can be done with the argument principle can be done with Rouche, the first has a statement that is often easier to apply.

Comment: @plop Regarding your first comment, I don't quite see what you are talking about with "winding" around 0. Can you please clarify?

Comment: It is the argument principle: (minus hypothesis) the number of zeros inside a simple loop is equal to the number of times that the image of the loop winds around zero. So, we look at the imaginary axis (traveled from $+i\infty$ to $-i\infty$) as the loop enclosing the right half plane. We need to see, how many times its image by $g$ winds around $0$.